# how to match all language characters like english, greek, chinese except the special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a display name field which i have to validate using JavaScript regex. We have to match  all language characters like chinese, german, spanish in addition to english language characters except special characters like *().
           I am struck on how to match those non-latin characters. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If your regular expression engine can match Unicode categories, the regex `\p{L}` matches any letter in any language.  JavaScript does not support Unicode categories.  If you use [XRegExp with the Unicode plugin](http://xregexp.com/plugins/), then you can do it like this in JavaScript:

```
XRegExp('^\\p{L}+$').test($input)
```

This will return true if $input consists of one or more letters and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Unluckily there isnt much support for unicode for unicode regular expressions in javascript

Comment: so i would use ajax (in case javascript is enabled)..
or simple server side validation

Answer (score 0):

I've used bits of [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/) for this kind of thing and it's worked as expected so far. There's Unicode plug-ins here: http://xregexp.com/plugins/